# How to replace all the text in the text in a loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

Sorry for my english =)
I need to replace some of the elements on a page. Here is my code:

```
var text1 = $('body').html().replace(/text1/, 'text11');
var text2 = $('body').html().replace(/text2/, 'text22');
var text3 = $('body').html().replace(/text3/, 'text33');
array = [text1, text2, text3];
      for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        $('body').html(array[i])
      };
```

But to replace only the first and third, if you remove the third element array, first and second is changed. Please tell me how to do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var items = [
    { find: /text1/, replace: 'text11' },
    { find: /text2/, replace: 'text22' },
    { find: /text3/, replace: 'text33' }
];
var text = $('body').html();

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++)
{
    var item = items[i];
    text = text.replace(item.find, item.replace);
}

$('body').html(text);
```

Comment: FWIW, there is no need in RegEx.

Answer (score 2):

That's because the original body html remains unchanged when the variables are evaluated. You would need to chain the replaces or use the previous variables for another replaces:

```
var text1 = $('body').html().replace(/text1/, 'text11');
var text2 = text1.replace(/text2/, 'text22');
var text3 = text2.replace(/text3/, 'text33');
```

And then you don't need any iterations..

```
$('body').html(text3);
```

Comment: chaining usually refers to `input.replace(...).replace(...).replace(...)...`

Comment: @JanDvorak. Re-read the post. "chain the replaces **or use the previous variables**"